# How can I modify animate() speed in three.js with html range slider?

Tags: three.js

I would like to be able to control the update speed of the animate() with a range slider, e.g.

```
<input type="range" id="speedSlider" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" style="width: 50px;">
```

I am using a model loaded with FBX. I am rotating an element of the model from a custom data array (`movementData`) as shown in the below code. I thought I could use `function modifySpeed(e) { var speed = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement; mixer.timeScale = speed.value;}` but nothing seems to happen. Can you help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    let clock = new THREE.Clock();

    let mixer, rightArm;

    var timeCounter = 0;

    var movementData = [32,43,12,33,23,12,6,54,7,23,8,43,9,12,10,
                        35,11,54,12,34,13,12,14,23,15,43,16,54,17,
                        65,18,87,19,98,20,1,21,2,22,3,23,4,24,5,25,
                        6,26,7,27,8,28,9,29,10,30,11,31,12,32,13,33,
                        14,34,15,35,16,36];

    init();
    animate();

    var speedSlider = document.getElementById("speedSlider");
    speedSlider.addEventListener("input", modifySpeed);

    function init() {

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.set( 100, 200, 300 );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

        // controls
        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.target.set( 0, 100, 0 );
        controls.update();

        // lighting
        const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
        hemiLight.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
        scene.add( hemiLight );
        const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        dirLight.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
        dirLight.castShadow = true;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.top = 180;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 100;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.left = - 120;
        dirLight.shadow.camera.right = 120;
        scene.add( dirLight );

        // ground
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
        mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add( mesh );

        const grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
        grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
        grid.material.transparent = true;
        scene.add( grid );

        // model
        const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
        loader.load( '{% static 'ybot.fbx' %}', function ( object ) {

            rightArm = object.getObjectByName( 'mixamorigRightArm' );

            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );

            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }
            });
            scene.add( object );
        });

    }

    function resizeCanvasToDisplaySize() {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      const width = canvas.clientWidth;
      const height = canvas.clientHeight;
      if (canvas.width !== width ||canvas.height !== height) {
        // you must pass false here or three.js sadly fights the browser
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        // set render target sizes here
      }
    }

    function modifySpeed(e) {
        var speed = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
        mixer.timeScale = speed.value;
    }

    function animate() {
    
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        const delta = clock.getDelta();

        if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta );

        resizeCanvasToDisplaySize();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        render();

    }

    function render() {
        rightArm.rotation.y = movementData[timeCounter][0];
        timeCounter += 1;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use setTimeout instead

```
<input type="range" id="speedSlider" min="1" max="60" step="1" style="width: 50px;">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var speedSlider = document.getElementById("speedSlider");

    speedSlider.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        speedLevel = parseInt(this.value);
    });

    startButton.onclick = function StartClicked() {
        startAnimation();
    }

    function startAnimation() {

        // Play animation with set speed interval
        timer = window.setTimeout(startAnimation, 1000/speedLevel);

    // Do stuff here...

    }


</script>
```